# Input related function not running after appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, which appends a text input into a well on focus, and hides it if the input is null. The problem is it only works for the original input field, the second input field generated won`t activate this function on focus. Any ideas why?

```
$('input:text')
.on('focus', function()
{
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val() == "")
  {
    numItems++;
    $($this.parent().append($('<input type="text" value ="" id="item' + numItems + '"></input>')));
  }
})
.on('blur', function()
{
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val() == "")
  {
    $this.hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
$('input:text')
.on('focus', function()
```

to

```
$(document)
.on('focus','input:text', function()
```

Comment: Just to explain this a bit, using `.on()` with an element only attaches that behaviour to elements of that type that exist when the function is run -- if you subsequently add extra elements to the DOM the behaviour won't be registered on it. If you delegate the behaviour to the document instead, it will also cover matching elements that are added later. Check out the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more detail (specifically, under the heading "Direct and Delegated Events").

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm!
And thanks for the explanation Zaid, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No worries, added a link to the docs if you want some further reading :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could delegate to the immediate parent to which the input is being appended.

```
$("#parentOfInput").on('focus','input:text', function(){
    //Handler
});
```

This is slightly more efficient than @sudhir's answer.

This will ensure that the event is intercepted before it bubbles all the way up to the document root.